# Change row color by weekday

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

Based on the weekday, I want the correct day to light up.

[Screenshot of what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1q2a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following formula in the conditional formatting tab:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=1,"Monday",IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=2,"Tuesday",IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=3,"Wednesday",IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=4,"Thursday",IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=5,"Friday",IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=6,"Saturday",IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)=7,"Sunday",)))))))`

Please use **Text contains** as the option (you're also free to use *Text is exactly* option as well):

[image: Conditional formatting]